# Highchart line chart circle around datalabel

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm plottting a highchart line graph with datalabel. Can I draw a circle around the datalabel? if no, is there any chart library that can do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [borderRadius](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.column.dataLabels)

```
borderRadius: 40
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/p6Ufv/